# I need the dropdown menu to open downwards instead of sideways. How to have menu do that?

Tags: html, css

Problem with launching of the dropdown menu

I tried to see if it was possible to use the position or text-align properties of CSS.

```css
  .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar a, .dropdown-content a{
      float: right;
      color: white;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
      background: red;
      color: black;
    }
    
    .navbar a:active{
      background: green;
      color: black;
    }
        
    .dropdown-content {
      display: none;
      background-color: #333;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div class = "navbar">
    <a href = "#">Page 6</a>
    <a href = "#">Page 5</a>
    <a href = "#">Page 4</a>
    <a href = "#">Page 3</a>
    <a href = "#">Page 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <ul>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Dropdown menu is opening sideways, to the left of the dropdown button, in the navbar instead of downwards. How to make it go downwards?

Answer (score 2):

Nest your menus and sub menus in an [unordered list](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)

```
<ul id='menu'>
   <li><a href='#'>Menu</a>
     <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>Submenu1</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Submenu2</a></li>
         <li><a href='#'>Submenu3</a></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
```

Check out [this JSSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eyelyn/4TmDu/) on how to setup the stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the dropdown-content absolutely positioned and allow overflow on the navbar. So, your css should look something like this:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}

.navbar a{
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar > a, .dropbtn {
  float: right;
}

.navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background: red;
  color: black;
}

.navbar a:active{
  background: green;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: #333;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class = "navbar">
<a href = "#">Page 6</a>
<a href = "#">Page 5</a>
<a href = "#">Page 4</a>
<a href = "#">Page 3</a>
<a href = "#">Page 2</a>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle with the results: https://jsfiddle.net/dLmr7wbk/